# Why type inference becomes less "permissive" if a method gets overloaded?

Tags: scala

Please, see the program below:

```
sealed trait Hierarchy
case class Leaf1() extends Hierarchy
case class Leaf2() extends Hierarchy

// I could make it [+T], but it used to compile without it.
class Container[T](val things: Seq[T])

object Container {
  def apply[T](things: T*): Container[T] = {
    new Container(Seq(things:_*))
  }
}

class Doer(things: Container[Hierarchy])

object Doer {
  def apply(things: Container[Hierarchy]): Doer = {
    new Doer(things)
  }

// Does not compile if uncommented.
//  def apply(things: Hierarchy*): Doer = {
//    new Doer(Container(things: _*))
//  }
}

class Test1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Doer(Container(Leaf1()))
  }
}
```

I have the generic container `Container[T]` which is invariant in `T`; and a way (`Container.apply()`) to construct it from an arglist `T*`.

Now notice the method `Doer.apply` which takes an argument of the type `Container[Hierarchy]`. Obviously, it cannot take an argument of `Container[Leaf1]`, but the original code does compile, i.e., Scala seems to infer that `Container(Leaf1())` has the type `Container[Hierarchy]`.

But if I uncomment the overload for the `Doer.apply()`, I get the error below. That is, Scala starts thinking that `Container(Leaf1())` has the type `Container[Leaf1]`.

> Error:(29, 5) overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
>   (things: Hierarchy*)Doer    (things: Container[Hierarchy])Doer 
>   cannot be applied to (Container[Leaf1])
>       Doer(Container(Leaf1()))
>       ^

Could you please explain what is going on here?

I could make the `Container` covariant in `T` (e.g., it is an immutable container), but I'd like to first understand what's going on.

Scala 2.11.7, JDK 1.8u45

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type inference works differently when there are overloaded identifiers. Looking at   http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution, it says:

> Let ℬ be the set of alternatives in  that are applicable to expressions (e1,…,en) of types (shape(e1),…,shape(en)). If there is precisely one alternative in ℬ, that alternative is chosen.
>
> Otherwise, let S1,…,Sm be the vector of types obtained by typing each argument with an undefined expected type. For every member m in ℬ one determines whether it is applicable to expressions (e1,…,em) of types S1,…,Sm. It is an error if none of the members in ℬ is applicable.

So, in this case, multiple alternatives are possible, so the argument is typed "with an undefined expected type". This means that the `T` in `Container.apply` has no typing information to lean on, other than the LUB of the values passed to it.

The resulting type is a `Container[Leaf1]`, which is obviously not a valid `Container[Hierarchy]`, given the invariance of `Container`.

When overloading is not present, there is an expected type, and `Container[Hierarchy]` is an acceptable type, given the type bounds.

Other examples that fail to compile due to lack of an expected type:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val container = Container(Leaf1())
  Doer(container)
}
```

gives rise to:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Container[Leaf1]
[error]  required: Container[Hierarchy]
[error] Note: Leaf1 <: Hierarchy, but class Container is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]     Doer(container)
[error]          ^
[error] one error found
```

And to show that the LUB of the values passed to `Container` is used when there is an undefined expected type:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  Doer(Container(Leaf1(), Leaf2()))
}
```

gives the error

```
overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
[error]   (things: Hierarchy*)Doer <and>
[error]   (things: Container[Hierarchy])Doer
[error]  cannot be applied to (Container[Product with Serializable with Hierarchy])
[error]     Doer(Container(Leaf1(), Leaf2()))
[error]     ^
[error] one error found
```

Interestingly, in this last case, the error goes away if you define `Hierarchy` as `extends Product with Serializable`, as the LUB is now just `Hierarchy`.